# How to add format 0.00 for every amount in Oracle

Tags: oracle

[image]

I would like to add format 0.00 in every amount. Here is the sample value of the amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Add" it?

- If you meant to *update* table contents, you meant wrong. Column datatype looks like `NUMBER` and values are stored correctly. Don't even think of modifying column datatype to `VARCHAR2` so that you'd *force* two decimals to those values
- If you meant to *display* values with two decimals then e.g. apply `TO_CHAR` function while selecting that value:

  ```
  SQL> with test (amount) as
    2    (select 123    from dual union all
    3     select   3.43 from dual union all
    4     select   2.7  from dual
    5    )
    6  select amount,
    7         to_char(amount, '999G999G990D00') as new_amount
    8  from test;

      AMOUNT NEW_AMOUNT
  ---------- ---------------
         123          123.00
        3.43            3.43
         2.7            2.70
  ```

  Alternatively, if that's for reporting purposes, most (if not all) tools let you specify format mask for numeric values, so - set any format you find appropriate.

Comment: In the sample date provided it looks like the the AMOUNT column is a varchar2, e.g. it has both `5000.00` and `490` (it's also left-aligned). Therefore I'd guess we should first convert to a number, perhaps handling invalid values somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the number format model in `to_char` as follows:

```
TO_CHAR(number_column, 'FM9999999999D00')
```

Please note that you need to use number of 9s more than or equal to max length in your column.

Example:

```
SELECT '2000000.00' AS NUM, TO_CHAR(2000000.00, 'FM9999999999D00') as formatted_num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5000.00', TO_CHAR(5000.00, 'FM9999999999D00') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '490', TO_CHAR(490, 'FM9999999999D00') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1', TO_CHAR(1, 'FM9999999999D00') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '526', TO_CHAR(526, 'FM9999999999D00') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '900000.00', TO_CHAR(900000.00, 'FM9999999999D00') FROM DUAL;


NUM        FORMATTED_NUM 
---------- --------------
2000000.00 2000000.00    
5000.00    5000.00       
490        490.00        
1          1.00          
526        526.00        
900000.00  900000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

As your 'amount' column appears to be a varchar2, you should first convert it to a number using `to_number()` and then convert to result to a formatted string with `to_char()`. Note that the result will be a string and not a number. If you want an actual number formatted a particular way, that will be a job for the client (Excel etc).

(I am using the built-in type `sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll` just as a convenient way to construct some test data without creating a table and populating it.)

```
with demo (amount) as (
    select column_value
    from   sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
           ('2000000.00', '5000.00', '490', '1', '526', '900000.00')
)
select amount
     , to_char(to_number(amount), 'FM9999999999D00')
from   demo;

AMOUNT               TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(AMOUNT),'FM9999999999D00')
-------------------- --------------------------------------------
2000000.00           2000000.00
5000.00              5000.00
490                  490.00
1                    1.00
526                  526.00
900000.00            900000.00
```

Since the column contains strings, it is possible that there will be invalid values that cause the conversion to fail:

```
with demo (amount) as (
    select column_value
    from   sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
           ( '2000000.00', '5000.00', '490', '1', '526', '900000.00', 'banana' )
)
select amount
     , to_char(to_number(amount), 'FM9999999999D00')
from   demo;

ORA-01722: invalid number
```

From 12c you can provide a default value for these cases:

```
with demo (amount) as (
    select column_value
    from   sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
           ( '2000000.00', '5000.00', '490', '1', '526', '900000.00', 'banana' )
)
select amount
     , to_char(to_number(amount default null on conversion error), 'FM9999999999D00')
from   demo;

AMOUNT               TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(AMOUNTDEFAULTNULLONCONVERSIONERROR),'FM9999999999D00')
-------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2000000.00           2000000.00
5000.00              5000.00
490                  490.00
1                    1.00
526                  526.00
900000.00            900000.00
banana
```